# Performing semantic analysis in text

Tags: nlp, semantic-web

I want to perform semantic analysis on some text similar to YAGO[[1]](http://www2007.org/papers/paper391.pdf). But I have no structure in the text to identify entities and relationships. One way is I use POS tagging and then identify subject and predicates in the sentences[[2]](http://ailab.ijs.si/delia_rusu/Papers/is_2007.pdf). But still I cannot establish what relationships exist between them.
How should I go about this?

For example:

```
Albert Einstein was born in 1879.
```

Should result in:

```
AlbertEinstein BORNIN   1879
subject        relation predicate
```

My aim to look for better approaches to find subjects, predicates and relationships in raw text.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Please check if I have made the question more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is essentially **Natural Language Understanding**, a subfield of Natural Language Processing, which again is a subfield of Computational Linguistics ~ often thought as the engineering arm.

You could do semantic parsing or relation extraction. Either are fine for this task. I decided to read through Suchanek *et al* (2007) and you will realise that it is ontology based, where the relations are extracted into a predefined ontological template where aixoms are predifed (e.g. **BORNIN**). I personally think this is far to restrictive for general intelligence but works great with weak ai problems [narrow domains]. Much more interesting work has been happening over the years such as ontology driven information extraction, where the algorithms are trained on the ontology rather than having a corpus annotated by an ontology. One PhD study that comes to mind is McDowell Thesis and the [Yildiz & Miksch (2007) paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-74484-9_57#page-1).

Regardless and without going off topic, there is a really interesting open source Python GUI driven project called **iepy** at the moment being developed by a firm called [Machinalis](http://www.machinalis.com/) which is based on django. It allows for rule based and machine learning based information extraction. I highly recommend you check it out -> Tried and tested by myself. Also, I'm not affiliated with this company.

https://github.com/machinalis/iepy

According to the documentation:

> IEPY is an open source tool for Information Extraction focused on
>   Relation Extraction.
>
> To give an example of Relation Extraction, if we are trying to find a
>   birth date in:
>
> "John von Neumann (December 28, 1903 – February 8, 1957) was a
>   Hungarian and American pure and applied mathematician, physicist,
>   inventor and polymath." then IEPY's task is to identify "John von
>   Neumann" and "December 28, 1903" as the subject and object entities of
>   the "was born in" relation.
>
> It's aimed at: users needing to perform Information Extraction on a
>   large dataset. scientists wanting to experiment with new IE
>   algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

The task you attempt to solve is called [relation extraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationship_extraction), while semantic analysis has much broader meaning (honestly, I can't say for sure what does it mean now).

Relation extraction is an open research problem, so I suggest to review the field - for example, start from the chapter 2.3 of [Mining text data](http://ir.nmu.org.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/144935/d1784ebed3eab2708026b202b2b65309.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) book or [A Review of Relation Extraction](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~nbach/papers/A-survey-on-Relation-Extraction.pdf) paper (which is a little older - 2007). Then continue research by following citing or cited-by links; finally, try to implement approach that looks most promising: for example, if you know that your data is rather formal (all sentences are short and share similar strict structure), then try something like pattern-based approaches; and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Stanford parser can do it :) You need to look at the dependency parser though. Have a look at the bottom of this page: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml:

subject: nsubj(snapped, rain), 
 or direct object: dobj(shut, hub))
 ...

Or have a look at this page (Stanford Dependencies): http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml

And to understand the annotations have a look at this: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf

And for your particular example, use Stanford "***collapsed***" dependency parser which for a given sentence will produce predicates like born_in(Einstein,1879), which is very similar to what you want.